# Hartshorne's algebraic geometry ; geometric understanding and intuition for intersection multiplicity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading section $7$ of the book.

He defines intersection multiplicity as

> Let $Y$ be a projective variety of dimension $r$. Let $H$ be a hypersurface not containing $Y$. Then by (7.2) $Y\cap H=Z_{1}\cup ...\cup Z_{s},$ where $Z_{j}$ are projective varieties of dimension $r-1$. Let $p_{j}$ be the homogeneous prime ideal of $ Z_{j}$. We define intersection multiplicity of $Y$ and $H$ along $Z_{j}$ to be $i(Y,H;Z_{j})$ = multiplicity of module  $S/(I_{Y}+I_{J})$ at $p_{j}$.

And multiplicity of module at its minimal prime $p$ means the length of 
$M_{p}$ over $S_{p}$.

I want to ask what is the geometrical interpretation of this definition. What does it mean intuitively? I understand this algebraically but i have no geometric feeling for the definition .

Comment: Take, for instance, in $\Bbb A^2_{\Bbb R}$ (since, let's face it, most of our intuition comes from there), the variety $Z(x^2-y)$ and the hypersurface $Z(y)$. They intersect at the origin. That intersection multiplicity is $2$, because not only do they intersect, but they also have the same tangents.

Comment: Sir , Can you please elaborate .

Comment: I fixed a typo, sorry (I wrote $Z(x-y)$ instead of $Z(y)$). There is not much to elaborate on. Intersection multiplicity is an algebraic way of asking about the analytic concept of the degree of a root.

Comment: @Arthur Sir ,What does degree of a zero mean .Is it related to degree of polynomial.

Comment: It is related, yes, but not quite the same. Take the two functions $f(x)=x(x-1)$ and $g(x)=x^2$. $f$ has two zeroes (at $x=0$ and $x=1$), however, if you draw the graph, you see that $f$ just crosses straight through the $x$-axis. $g$, on the other hand, only has one zero, buy it's a different kind. The graph aligns itself with the $x$-axis, and is, for all intents and purposes, _parallel_ to the $x$-axis at the origin. That is a zero of degree two. It is, in a sense, two roots on top of one another. The number of those "on top of one another" is what the length of $M_p$ over $S_p$ measures.